# What does "doublets and triplets are juvenile when overused" mean?

Tags: meaning

From reading [this document, page 212](http://www.deirdremccloskey.com/docs/pdf/Article_86.pdf), I am wondering what does "**doublets and triplets are juvenile when overused**" mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When used about writing, [juvenile](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/juvenile) is generally a disapproving term meaning "silly and typical of a child".

The article identifies various unsavoury traits in eighth grade writing: eighth graders are 13-14 years old- ie children.

One particular unsavoury trait is the overuse of doublets and triplets. The examples that he provides are

> doublet: Keynes and the Keynesians
> triplet: faith, hope and charity